# yii: retrieve just the form name class when using namespaces

Tags: yii

I have a code similar to this to handle a form submission:

```
use \my-project\web\models\forms\RegisterOrganizationForm;
...
var_dump($_POST);die();
$model=new LoginForm;
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
```

The output of that var_dump is (well, just the part regarding the values of the form):

> ["\my-project\web\models\forms\LoginForm"]=> array(1) {...

As you can see the namespace has been added (I didn't expect this..), so, how can I get just something like this below when vardumping??:

```
["LoginForm"]=> array(1) {...
```

Javier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are calling die() before you set the model attributes to the data received by the form.

Second you are doing a `var_dump` of `$_POST` instead do `var_dump` `$_POST['LoginForm']`

Third why do you want to do a var_dump if you want to see what is being sent back from the form use a tool like firebug for FireFox or developer tools in chrome

Comment: Well, i added the var_dump() since var_dump($_POST['LoginForm']) returns "undefined index". It's just my way to debug, thanks anyway, the next time i will use FB or similar. Do you any solution to my question?

Comment: if you are just using it for debug it is not important if you are getting the complete path!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you.

Patch the following file:

/path/to/yii/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php

Find the method 'resolveName', replace it with the following:

```
/**
 * Resolves a class name, removing namespaces.
 */
public static function resolveClassName($model){
    return end(explode('\\',get_class($model)));
}

/**
 * Generates input name for a model attribute.
 * Note, the attribute name may be modified after calling this method if the name
 * contains square brackets (mainly used in tabular input) before the real attribute name.
 * @param CModel $model the data model
 * @param string $attribute the attribute
 * @return string the input name
 */
public static function resolveName($model,&$attribute)
{
    if(($pos=strpos($attribute,'['))!==false)
    {
        if($pos!==0)  // e.g. name[a][b]
            return self::resolveClassName($model).'['.substr($attribute,0,$pos).']'.substr($attribute,$pos);
        if(($pos=strrpos($attribute,']'))!==false && $pos!==strlen($attribute)-1)  // e.g. [a][b]name
        {
            $sub=substr($attribute,0,$pos+1);
            $attribute=substr($attribute,$pos+1);
            return self::resolveClassName($model).$sub.'['.$attribute.']';
        }
        if(preg_match('/\](\w+\[.*)$/',$attribute,$matches))
        {
            $name=self::resolveClassName($model).'['.str_replace(']','][',trim(strtr($attribute,array(']['=>']','['=>']')),']')).']';
            $attribute=$matches[1];
            return $name;
        }
    }
    return self::resolveClassName($model).'['.$attribute.']';
}
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. For anyone who thinks this is silly or unnecessary, client side validators don't work because you can't select an element by ID with backslashes using JavaScript (or at least with jQuery)